# Why always getting null(context.getContentResolver().insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);)

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

```
if (groupId == 0) {
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        contentValues.put(Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        contentValues.put(Groups.TITLE, SAMPLE_GROUP_NAME);
        contentValues.put(Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY, true);

        final Uri newGroupUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        groupId = ContentUris.parseId(newGroupUri);
    }
```

I have these line of code in a class ContactManager of the project SampleSyncAdapter which i have downloaded from Android Developer website(samples for sdk api 16).

My problem is that

```
context.getContentResolver().insert(Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

this line always return null..,.
Why and what is the solution of this problem..,.

Comment: have you initialize context variable?

Comment: `null` means that the insert failed and no new group was created, check logcat if there is some error message regarding that.